# Can I avoid casting when testing a Supplier of Streams

Tags: assertj

When using AssertJ, can I avoid casting when testing a Supplier of Streams?

I tried looking at open issues and most point to https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/683 but I don't think it is a direct match.

```java
        Supplier<Stream<String>> supplier = 
                 () -> Stream.of("String1", "String2");
        assertThat(supplier).isNotNull()
                .extracting(Supplier::get)
                .isInstanceOf(Stream.class)
                .satisfies((stream) ->
                        assertThat((Stream)stream)
                                .contains("String1", "String2"));
```

The test works but I would like to avoid the casting of the Stream if possible.
Thanks.

Comment: Does starting with `assertThat(supplier.get())...` solve your use case? The nullcheck of the supplier is not that useful in testing, an NPE has the same benefit.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with tkruse comment!

I just want to add that in AssertJ Core next version (3.13.0), you will be able to use `asInstanceOf` to cast the object under test and access type specific assertion, see https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/pull/1498

```java
Object value = 0;
assertThat(values).asInstanceOf(INTEGER).isZero();
```

In your case, I believe you would be able to write:

```java
assertThat(supplier).isNotNull()
                    .extracting(Supplier::get)
                    .asInstanceOf(STREAM)
                    .satisfies(stream -> assertThat(stream).contains("String1", 
                            "String2"));
```